# Errors traitement priority

Tags: fiware-orion

(Moved from https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2342):

What is the priority between the errors proceeding?

For example if we have a BadRequest error (such us an invalid URL instead of /v2/entities we have /v2/eeeentities) and Content length required error (no payload in the POST request) in the same request which one shall be raised?

In general if we have more than one error in the request what is the order of errors treatment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orion implements and "early detect" strategy, so in the case of simultaneous errors, the "shallowest" one tends to be reported before. For example, parsing errors are detected before the request progresses to database processing layer so other potential database-related error may raise. But within the same category (e.g. parsing errors of different kinds) it isn't any predefined order.

Having said that, it isn't any piece of documentation with a ordered list of errors by priority. That documentation could be generated from to the source code, but it would be hard and doesn't work the effort. From a practical point of view, note that if your request has problems A and B, at the end most of the times it doesn't matter if Orion reports first A, you fix A, then report B that in the other way arround.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse but I forgot to mention that I am asking about the NGSI v2 specification and not orion implementation. I was looking to the NGSI v2 issues list (https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+milestone%3ANGSIv2SpecPending) when I opened the issue thought it will be in it. so my question is that in the specification what is the priority between the errors proceeding so that in the different implementations this priority will be respected, Thanks.

Comment: Specification doesn't specifies any order so it would be an implementation specific aspect how to deal with this. Although the specification may change (it is not yet closed) note that the problem I describe (if your request has problems A and B, at the end most of the times it doesn't matter if Orion reports first A, you fix A, then report B that in the other way arround) is not specific of particular implementation so probably specification shouldn't say anything regarding this.

Comment: I think the specification needs to clarify the order so that two different implementation returns the same result in case of two errors in the request. Thanks.